# sample size for 2x2x2 between-subjects factorial design

Tags: anova, sample-size, statistical-power, effect-size

I'd like to conduct an experiment of 2×2×2 between-subjects factorial design, but I have no idea for the minimum sample size.

Can someone help me to regard the sample size of my case ? Which test should I select in G*Power, and what parameters should be filled in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is a $2^3$ full factorial design. There are power calculation procedures for ANOVA for such designs which give you the number of replicates and take into account your design layout (number of factors and levels) and...

- desired power 1-$\beta$
- desired $\alpha$
- $\sigma$ of the response variable
- a minimum effect size to be detected

The latter is not as straightforward as in a simple two-sample test, because you are comparing $2^3 = 8$ experimental conditions. Which main effects *or even interactions* (4 in total) should the analysis be powered for? You probably have some prior knowledge about differences in the effects of the three factors on the response. A typical approach then is to take the smallest effect that has practical importance irrespective of the factor.

For example, if you expect a large effect of temperature and a small effect of pressure, it might not be sensible to power your experiment to detect a difference in means between the two temperature conditions. Rather, think about which effect of pressure would still be interesting.

There is, among others, the R function `BDEsize::Size.full()` to run such an analysis. (see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/BDEsize/man/Size.Full.html)). There are also GPower functions for such N-way ANOVAS, as demonstrated in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDL0zfG0Lf8).

Final remarks:

- The power will also depend on the specified model (e.g. including or excluding the three-way interaction)
- Depending on your appliaction, it might be useful to estimate factor effects as precise as you need them (e.g., in manufacturing) rather than testing a null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks stefgehrig. I tried to run the calculation in GPower by selecting "F tests" and "ANOVA: Fixed effects, special, main effects and interactions". The type of power analysis is "A priori: Compute required sample size". I input effect size=0.1, α=0.05, power 1-β=0.8, numerator df=1, number of groups=8. The output parameters show that total sample size=787. Does it mean that I have to recruit 787 participants for the project (i.e., 99 per group) or 787 participants per group?? Also, I'm struggling in setting the effect size at 0.1 or 0.25. My proj. is about advertisement's persuasiveness.

Comment: I never used GPower, so I cannot tell you about their conventions, but that should all be in their manual. If you have problems thinking about effect size in terms of standardized units, you can transform it back to the measurement scale